# Rotation landscape and Portrait

Tags: ios, uiview

I have problem in rotation in UIView, In UIView I have UIimage and UI toolbar
when I change different rotation then  UIImage and UIToolBar should also be changed

Answer (score 1):

for iOS 6, In your view controller do this,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait
         | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown
         | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

This will make orientation for Portrait, upside-down portrait and landscape left.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

http://goodliffe.blogspot.com/2009/12/iphone-forcing-uiview-to-reorientate.html

check this site for more detail.